# How do I troubleshoot the touch screen on an HTC Evo Shift?

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, htc-evo

My husband's HTC Evo Shift took a swim in some iced coffee and the touch screen doesn't work at all anymore. I did a full factory reset, which didn't accomplish anything. The screen doesn't respond at all. I can flip it open and use the keyboard, but that's not hardly convenient.

So ... what do I try next?  I'm game to experiment -- he got a new phone. I just can't accept that this one is kaput.

Comment: I realized I thought the phone was an HTC Sense. It isn't, it's an HTC Evo Shift.

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings->Developer Options->Show touchscreen touches.  Unfortunately, HTC likes to move these settings around between versions so I don't know if it will work for you.

Replacing the digitizer is possible on many HTCs, I did it on my EVO 3D.  But that's probably what has failed.  Condensation will confuse it and make it stop functioning .

Answer (score 0):

There's probably moisture in the device. If so, you need to take it apart and clean it (and maybe replace some parts): https://www.google.com/search?q=teardown+htc+evo+shift

Comment: Oh? Will try that.